# How can I log removed file name in elFinder with Client-event API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, elfinder

I am trying to create Ajax logging feature for [elFinder](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder) so I added event handlers:

```
'elfinder': {
    handlers : {
        add : function(event, elfinderInstance) {
            console.log(event.data);
            //console.log(event.data.selected); // selected files hashes list
        },
        remove : function(event, elfinderInstance) {
            console.log(event.data);
            //console.log(event.data.selected); // selected files hashes list
        }
    }
}
```

[Client-event-API](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Client-event-API)

From `add` event I get all data I need, part of the nested object data for example:

```
hash: "l1_UypQLTJfOC9TY3JlZW5zaG90IDIwMjEtMDMtMTEgYXQgMTUuMTguNDcucG5n"
isowner: false
mime: "image/png"
name: "Screenshot 2021-03-11 at 15.18.47.png"
phash: "l1_UypQLTJfOA"
read: 1
size: "60591"
tmb: 1
ts: 1616364008
url: "/php/../files/S%2AP-2_8/Screenshot%202021-03-11%20at%2015.18.47.png"
write: 1
```

Most importantly `url` and `name` of the added file.

But on `remove` I get only:

```
0: "l1_UypQLTJfOC9TY3JlZW5zaG90IDIwMjEtMDMtMTEgYXQgMTUuMTguNDcucG5n"
length: 1
```

How can I log removed file name in eFinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because the path encoding method can be changed with the volume
> driver, the client side does not implement a function to decode it.
>
> However, if it is the default encoding method, it can be decoded as
> follows.

```
var hash = 'l1_RG93bmxvYWRz';
var encPath = hash.substr(hash.indexOf('_')+1);
var path = '/'+atob(encPath.replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/').replace(/\./g, '='));
```

Reference:
https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/issues/2011